# how to convert DialogResult form winform to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to convert the following methode from winform to WPF

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!EnterNewSettings())
        DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
}
```

I've done this, but does'nt work.

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 { 
if (!EnterNewSettings())
 MessageBoxResult result = MessageBoxResult.None;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly doens't work?

Comment: What is not working? Can you explain the question bit clear?

Comment: what doesn't work is that the first code is a winform code i want to convert it to WPF

Comment: to WPF code like you know the dialogresult doesn't exist in WPF

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the logic to confirm and close your messagebox your self.

Create a Public Property Succes

```
Public bool Success {get;set;}
```

And have this implementation in your ok button if you can to close your form and have it succeed:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{ 
   if (!EnterNewSettings()){
   MessageBoxResult result = MessageBoxResult.None;
   }else{
      Success = true;
      Close();
   }
}
```

Then you can Check on the property Success

Could be i'm missing some syntax but i hope you get where it's going to :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the problem but in WPF [`Window.DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult.aspx) is `bool?` which means it can be either `true`, `false` or `null`, depending of what is the outcome. If you want to close WPF `Window` with success you need to set `DialogResult` to `true`. When you have `Button.IsDefault = "true"` then it will trigger click event on `ENTER` but won't close the dialog for you until `DialogResult` is set.

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{ 
   if (EnterNewSettings()) DialogResult = true;
}
```

and your `DialogResult` is passed as a result of `Window.ShowDialog()`

```
if (myDlg.ShowDialog() == true) ....
```

When you have `Button.IsCancel = "true"` then, on `ESC`, it will trigger click event and automatically close dialog with `DialogResult=False`

Answer (score 0):

```
    private MessageBoxResult isBlaBlaa()
    {
        Window w = new Window();
        w.Tag = MessageBoxResult.Cancel;

        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.Margin = new Thickness(30);

        grid.Children.Add(new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = "Bla blaa",
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 20)
        });

        Button btn;
        btn = new Button()
        {
            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
            HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left,
            Content = "Cancel",
            Width = 100,
            Height = 30,

        };
        btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => { w.Tag = MessageBoxResult.Cancel; w.DialogResult = false; });
        grid.Children.Add(btn);

        btn = new Button()
        {
            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
            HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            Content = "No",
            Width = 100,
            Height = 30,

        };
        btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => { w.Tag = MessageBoxResult.No; w.DialogResult = false; });
        grid.Children.Add(btn);

        btn = new Button()
        {
            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
            HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right,
            Content = "Yes",
            Width = 100,
            Height = 30,

        };
        btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => { w.Tag = MessageBoxResult.Yes; w.DialogResult = true; });
        grid.Children.Add(btn);


        w.Content = grid;

        w.ShowDialog();

        return (MessageBoxResult)w.Tag;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explainn how this solves the problem. Maybe showing only code won't help OP whats going on.